# How to implement Inheritance in Cakephp

Tags: php, oop, cakephp, inheritance, cakephp-2.1

I wanted to implement inheritance, As I followed [this article](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/santino83/2011/02/19/behavior_for_model_inheritance_the_missing_feature) I did not get database deign, I was only able to create the models as follows and I created file  InheritBehavior.php under Model/Behaviour as in the article. So how to design the database for these models to support inheritance

```
class Animal extends AppModel{
    var $name='Animal';
}

App::import('Model', 'Animal');
class Mammal extends Animal{
public $actsAs = array( 'Inherit' ); 
}   var $name= 'Mammal';

}


App::import('Model', 'Animal');
class Insect extends Animal{
    var $name='Insect';
}   

Animal: id, age
Mammal: id, no_of_legs ('age' is common)
Insect: id, no_of_wings ('age' is common)
```

What is the database design for this(**Multiple Table Inheritance**).

**Is it a good idea to use Inheritance instead of Associations(using hasOne and belongsTo)  for this type, Will this be well supported by cakephp ?**

Answer (score 5):

**Sort answer:** no, it is not a good idea.

In OOP it is recommended to always prefer composition over inheritance.

---

You are doing it wrong.

In OOP there is something we call [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (for *dumb down* version: [image](http://www.globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/liskov_substitution_principle_small.jpg)). This means, that you should not remove or fundamentally change functionality, when sub-classing.

Also, using animals as OOP example always ends up horribly. Classify following: whale(no legs), bat(has wings), lice(no wings). I guess you see the problem.

And one other thing. As CakePHP user you might not be aware of it, but in PHP5 we have define variables as either `private`, `public` or `protected`. Instead of PHP4-style `var`.